# How to create multiple search?

Tags: php, mysql

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (first_name LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name "; 
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");

  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  }
```

i need to do multiple search, with  first_name,last_name,middle_name,contact_no1 fields

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: use `OR` in your query and multiple bindValue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do search with all fields add fields in WHERE  with `OR`:

```
try {
  $keyword = trim($_GET["keyword"]);
  if ($keyword <> "" ) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 AND "
            . " (first_name LIKE :keyword OR last_name LIKE :keyword OR middle_name LIKE :keyword OR contact_no1 LIKE :keyword) ORDER BY first_name "; 
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":keyword", $keyword."%");

  } else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contacts WHERE 1 ORDER BY first_name ";
    $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function search($requestArray){
$sql = "";
if( isset($requestArray['firstname']) && isset($requestArray['lastname']) )  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_contacts` WHERE AND (`first_name` LIKE '%".$requestArray['search']."%' OR `last_name` LIKE '%".$requestArray['search']."%')";
if(isset($requestArray['firstname']) && !isset($requestArray['lastname']) ) $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_contacts` WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%".$requestArray['search']."%'";
if(!isset($requestArray['firstname']) && isset($requestArray['lastname']) )  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_contacts` WHERE `last_name` LIKE '%".$requestArray['search']."%'";

$STH  = $this->DBH->query($sql);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$someData = $STH->fetchAll();

return $someData;

}
```

I used this method in one of my project for searching with two field hope it could help you. where $requestArray will get the data from form and 'firstname' , 'lastname' are two key of the array which you will enter your searchbox and submit to search. I just showed you here the query style and before that you have tor trim the values.